# Listen to click event on items in ViewPager2 in android

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

What is the right way in Android to listen to click events on an item in a `ViewPager2` with Java?

My idea was to set on my instance of `ViewPager2` a custom `CustomAdapter` that extends `FragmentStateAdapter`. In the `CustomAdapter` I wanted to override the method `onCreateViewHolder(...)` that returns `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. The overridden method would inflate the view, set the onClickListener on the view and return a `new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)`.

The problem is, that in `FragmentStateAdapter` the method `onCreateViewHolder(...)` is `final`.

Answer (score 0):

Listening for click events from items in a Fragment should be done inside each Fragment to maintain the encapsulation of the Fragment.